# Cannot change my image using attr Property

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

```
  $("#ServiceID" + viewModel.ServiceID()).attr("src", viewModel.smallImageUrl());
```

`#ServiceID`(is my image id) and `viewmodel.ServiceID`(is my unique id) and viewmodel.smallImageUrl() is my image url in cdn

Change my Image based on my Unique id .But it does not works for me. I Dont know the exact syntax in jquery.

Comment: Check what's the result of `"#ServiceID" + viewModel.ServiceID()` and verify if there is any html element with that id.

Comment: A few things to check. Do `viewModel.ServiceID()` and `viewModel.smallImageUrl()` actually have values? Does `console.log($('#ServiceID" + viewModel.ServiceID()));` return anything?

Comment: Please provide some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: { title: "Image", field: "smallImageUrl", template: '<div align="center"><img  id="#=ServiceID #" height="50" width="50" src="#=smallImageUrl#" /></div>', width: 100 },    THis is my Image column in Grid

Comment: use prop instead of attr

Comment: Its MVVM, and the point is to abstract the Dom and the behavior, use the attr binding in KO!

Answer (score 0):

As @Anders already pointed out, Knockout promotes an MVVM approach. This means, for one, seperating the data from the presentation. This means that when you're doing jQuery in your viewmodel, you're doing it wrong (sorry if that sounds harsh).

The recommended approach would be the following: Find your image in your HTML and apply a binding to it so that the src is set to your viewmodel's property. So it would be something like this:

```
<img id="ServiceID3" data-bind="attr: { src: $root.smallImageUrl }" /> // $root points to the viewModel you've bound using ko.applyBindings
```

Somewhere in your JavaScript:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

In case this doesn't work, an easy way to debug if your viewmodel's observables hold the values that you expect them to hold, is to add a div to your page with the following binding:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div> // This will output the contents of your viewmodel as a string
```